# Delay useEffect until useSelector retrieves data from the Redux store in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I have a functional react component Tasks_1, and initially, I want to retrieve the userId from the redux store which successfully works.

After this, I want to use the userId in useEffect that I retrieved from the redux store to get data from the backend.

When useEffect runs it says there is an empty string retrieved from the state id. How can I make useEffect run after the state "id" is set from useState retrieving it from the store?

```
    function Tasks_1 () {
    
    const [id, setId] = useState('');
    
    const userId = useSelector((state) => state.id);
    const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);
    
    useEffect(() => {

        setId(userId);
    
        if (id !== '') {
            db.collection('users').doc(id).collection('tasks').onSnapshot((snapshot)=>{
                const tempTasks = [];
                snapshot.forEach(
                   doc => {
                       tempTasks.push(doc.data());
                   }
                )
                setTasks(tempTasks);
            });
        }
    
    }),[id];
    
    return (
        ...

   )

 }
```

Comment: Not quite understanding the issue - What makes your current approach not sufficient? I mean you have an if statement `if (id !== '')` which makes sure not to call the database if the id has not been set.

Comment: You forgot to add `userId` to `useEffect` dependencies.  It wound be updated when the value is retrieved.

Comment: Yea for some reason I would either receive infinite loop errors or "path is empty " error when taking a snapshot from the back end. I also see now that I was not using userId in the dependencies which was a concept I was not as familiar with until now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might get an infinite loop if you do get this to work the way you have it. Updating `id` using `setId` will cause a re-render and the useEffect will be called again since you changed `id` and so on....

I believe this would work:

```
const [id, setId] = useState('');

const userId = useSelector((state) => state.id);
const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {

      // this will make sure you only set id when userId
      // is a valid value, and it won't reset it every
      // serenader
    if(userId!=='' && id !== userId)
       setId(userId);

    if (id !== '') {
        db.collection('users').doc(id).collection('tasks').onSnapshot((snapshot)=>{
            const tempTasks = [];
            snapshot.forEach(
               doc => {
                   tempTasks.push(doc.data());
               }
            )
            setTasks(tempTasks);
        });
    }

}, [id, userId]);
```

and you would have to add `userId` to the array dependencies.

Comment: Yea sometimes I was getting an infinite loop error so I was not sure how to structure this so that the data from the back end was received after. let me try what you proposed!

Comment: in this instance would the useEffect have a reason to keep checking for a change in userID? just as a test for fun im consol.log(userId) and is keeps logging it at intervals almost but this did work for me!

Comment: @MattLaszcz useEffect get recalled every time either `id` or `userId` gets updated.  You will definitely have it happen at least 3x. Once initial render, 2d when you receive the updated value of `userId`, and third because you `setId` with the new `userId` causing another rerender.  After this it should only be called if these value are change externally.

Comment: ok maybe there is something else in my code i need to debug thats causing the id to be updating and causing the re-renders I am seeing then. Ill take a look for it.

Comment: try this to see if its not `userId` being update more than once.  `useEffect(()=> console.log('here'),[userId]);` add it in addition to you're current `useEffect`.  You can have more than one.

Comment: If you see here being console logged, its because of you're `useSelector((state) => state.id);` hook

Comment: when I added useEffect(()=> console.log('here'),[userId]);  with the other console.log commented out there is no more logging of it. The console.log that continuously logs was located just below the line where const userId was declared btw

Comment: I determined why this was happening: last line of your solution should be },[id, userId]); not }),[id, userId];

Comment: Yeah I didn't put the code in my editor. Sorry.  What editor are you using that didn't catch that if I might ask?

Comment: I am using VSC so I am surprised it didn't catch it! I just happened to notice it now